# jQuery copy text to cloned input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help to copy the html() from Volume Calculator to the respective input.
As it looks at the moment when I click the Copy button html from CalcSubTotal copied to all inputs with ID Capacity_.

```
$('#CopyCalculatorDivButton').click(function()
{
//var FormTable = $('#AddFieldsToFormDiv');
//var Capacity = FormTable.closest("tr").find("[id^='Capacity_']");
$("[id^='Capacity_']").val( $('#CalcSubTotal').html() );
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/3914/)

[image]

Comment: Could you show relevant HTML code as well?

Comment: You have multipe IDs with the same value. This is invalid HTML. It appears as though your counter isn't working.

Comment: I see now that the counter for the CALC button does not work. Because: $clone.find("input:text, select").val('').each(function ()

Comment: chepe263: have you seen JSFiddle link I provide ?

Comment: isherwood: this must be a way to use NAME only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add**

```
clickedRow = $(this).closest("tr");
```

To

```
$('input[name=CalculatorButton]').click(function () {
    clickedRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    $('#CalculatorDiv').window('open');
    $('#CalculatorDiv').find('input:first').focus();
});
```

**And use the context of that Row**

```
$("[id^='Capacity_']",clickedRow).val( $('#CalcSubTotal').html() );
```

**In**

```
$('#CopyCalculatorDivButton').click(function()
{
   //var FormTable = $('#AddFieldsToFormDiv');
   //var Capacity = FormTable.closest("tr").find("[id^='Capacity_']");
    $("[id^='Capacity_']",clickedRow).val( $('#CalcSubTotal').html() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XB3Wy/